# Problema con la lectura de una imagen en php html5

Tags: php, html5, img, src

Yo hago este link dentro de una página:

```
<li><p class="textoprog"> Download Programs in pdf<a class="pdf" href="<?php echo $progra ; ?>" TARGET="_blank"  ><?php echo "<img src='http://www.prueba.com.ar/web/mobile/images/pdf.jpg' border='0' width='25' height='25'>"?> </a></p></li>
```

pero no me muestra la imagen, al pedir que abra la imagen en otra pestaña para probar me muestra esta direccion:

```
http://www.prueba.com.ar////////////////////web/mobile/images/pdf.jpg
```

como veran me agrega  un monton de las / y el mensaje de error es que se ha redirigido la página demasiadas veces.

Alguien sabe porque ocurre eso, ya que esto lo uso habitualmente y en el Localhost funciona perfectamente
Si toco el link, lo abre correctamente. solo tengo problemas con la imagen

Comment: Utilizo, php 7 - mysql y apache

Comment: Haz un `echo $progra;` aparte y revisa lo que muestra, pues el `href` es el equivalente de esa variable que al parecer produce `http://www.prueba.com.ar////////////////////web/mobile/images/pdf.jpg`. Por otra parte, evita lo más que puedas la mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML, en tu código hay incluso un abuso de esta práctica, por ejemplo aquí no hay ninguna necesidad de abrir un bloque PHP: `<?php echo "<img src='http://www.prueba.com.ar/web/mobile/images/pdf.jpg' border='0' width='25' height='25'>"?>`

Comment: Muchas Gracias;